# Change name of entity in a list in WCF

Tags: wcf, entity

I am writing a WCFservice that exposes a list to front end. It will be like:

```
public List<customers> getCustomers()
{
   //code goes here like DB operations
}
```

Here customer List Contains following files

```
int Id{set;get;}

int CustomerName{set;get;}

int CustomerPlace{set;get;}
```

Here in this list I want Id being displayed as CustomerId. I cannot change the name of field as I am using some autommaper for database. So is there any thing which can Change Id to Customer Id?

Please Help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean i want to change Id to Customer Id While we are exposing to Service.I hope Displa anme attribute is for View Purpose.

Comment: Looks like you are sharing the model (the class you've mapped from database) in your service, and this is not good. You can create a service model, with `CustomerId` and use this model with your service. Service can have its own model, to serve the clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only for display purpose means create Custom model Like this

```
  [DataContract]
   public class Customers
   {      
     [DataMember]
     [Display(Name = "CustomerId")]
     public int Id{set;get;}

     [DataMember]
     public int CustomerName{set;get;}

     [DataMember]
     public int CustomerPlace{set;get;}
   }


   [MetadataType(typeof(Customers))]
   public partial class customers
  {   }
```

and use List like this `public List<Customers> getCustomers()`